# Shadow DOM confusion about styling - background-color not working properly on shadow elements (angular)

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

I'm having hard times trying to understand how :host elements should be styled

ex:

```html
// toggle.component.html
<p>toggle works!</p>
```

```
//toggle.component.scss
:host {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

This background-color is not shown unless I put on it any display property like block or inline-block, even tho the element clearly takes space having that p element inside

This causes me a lot of confusion especially when having to style related things in different components (example: I have a component table with other sub custom components such as table-row and table-header, which I cant style as I normally would because there are these shadow dom elements always in the middle)

Why does it act like that? How should I adapt to these shadow dom elems in case of ex: table ?
Any resource link would be highly appreciated

EDIT: I just found found out that using something like `height: 50%` on an element at the top level of a sub-component takes the. height relative to the first element it finds after the shadow element instead of the shadow element itself?? WHY?? Where is this explained ?

Still having this problem, hard to style a grid

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that shadow DOM elements take the default display which is inline, I didn't know that, I tought it was display: block since it's the one who makes most sense

So you have to do `:host { display: block }` on every component to have a consistent behavior

From Angular 9.1.0 there will be an option to generate components already with block display